# ANA domestic carry-on allowance: can I take a laptop bag as well as a rucksack?

Tags: hand-luggage, ana

I have a domestic flight (within Japan) booked with ANA; this is a single flight with no connecting international segment. The aircraft I'm flying on is a 777-200 from Tokyo-Haneda to Sapporo.

I've found, eventually, both "[Information Regarding Baggage [International Flights]](https://www.ana.co.jp/wws/uk/e/asw_common/prepare/baggage/index.html?menu=rule)", which obviously doesn't apply here, and "[Information on Domestic Flight-Baggage](https://www.ana.co.jp/wws/japan/e/local/domestic/prepare/baggage/index.html?menu=carry-rule)", though it doesn't answer the below question.

In short, what I want to know is can I take a laptop messenger bag along with a rucksack. Both are small enough to typically fit beneath the seat in front.

The international rules say:

> In addition to personal belongings (handbags, laptops, cameras, umbrellas, etc.), passengers are allowed to carry on only 1 pieceof baggage

Whereas the domestic rules say:

> […] other than personal belongings (hand bags, cameras, umbrellas, etc.) […]

Given the "etc." in both of these, it isn't clear to me how big a personal belonging can be! Certainly my laptop bag is smaller than some handbags, but its omission from the latter list (and the fact it's the only one omitted) worries me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having asked a friend who has lived in Japan for decades, I just went ahead and risked it. In the end, nobody as much as raised an eyebrow, much less stopped me to question it whatsoever. The overhead lockers were pretty much entirely empty, so there was no problem with storing it. Therefore, it'd seem like there's no issue with taking a small laptop messenger bag as a "personal belonging".

Comment: Additionally, Domestic Flights in Japan usually allow you to bring the same in-flight luggage as they allow on their international flights. Usually; 1 piece of cabin luggage plus a handbag, "slim" laptop bag - with laptop, a camera in or without a small camera bag or equivalent item. You should note that their cabin luggage allowances are smaller (as their overhead compartments are usually smaller) although they usually allow slightly larger cabin luggage if you are transferring from an international flight. This has been my experience the times I have flown JAL and ANA (as well as some LCCs).

Answer (score -2):

I just copy the information from your link

> Size/Weight (100 seats or more *1)
>
> Total linear dimensions 115cm or less (55cm x 40cm x 25cm or less)*
>
> 10kg or less, Combined weight of all personal belongings.
>
> Size/Weight (Less than 100 seats *2)
>
> Total linear dimensions 100cm or less (45cm x 35cm x 20cm or less)*
>
> 10kg or less, Combined weight of all personal belongings.
>
> Because of the limited storage space available on the plane, please
>   check in the baggage exceeding a length of each side (*) even if the
>   total sum of three dimensions is less than 115cm (100cm).In addition,
>   if you wish to carry on baggage with you, check with ANA staff.(We
>   will inspect the size of your baggage.) If the baggage cannot be
>   stored in the in-cabin storage space, even if it is within the
>   specified size, we will accept the baggage as checked baggage and
>   store it in the cargo room.
>
> *1:773/772/777/789/78P/78R/76P/763/ 32A/32F/738/73H/73L/73P/ 737/73D/73X/735
>   *2:Q4A/Q82/CR7/CRJ

Comment: Both of those links state that the given dimensions are "in addition to personal belongings".

Comment: @gsnedders do you think personal rucksack belongs to "personal belongings"